# Django - Static files not found on ubuntu

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu, django-staticfiles

I currently stuck on handling static files with django on lubuntu, keep receiving error 404, file not found.

I've tried multiple possibilities that I've googled, but none of them worked in my case.

I have my static files under static folder in my main project's folder.

settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first_app',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

Could you give me advice what is the bast way to handle static files on ubuntu or if you see any solution in my case?

Comment: Did you have deployed your peoject into a server as apache ?

Comment: Do you have a `STATIC_ROOT` setting? Have you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: I think that not. Can you give me a hint how to do this?

Comment: I recommend reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/), its fairly comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this tutorial, [Deploying Your Application (Option #1) - Deploy to a Linux Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds&list=WL&index=59&t=4095s)

It goes through all the steps to successfully deploying your app into a ubuntu server.